# Determine when a control is selected in Expression Blend

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, expression-blend

I'm building an extension for Expression Blend 4. My extension is visible as palette in Expression Blend.

When a user selects a ContentControl, i want to display some options in my extension pallette. So my question is how can i determine when a ContentControl (or another control) is selected? Thanks, Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the following link for design-time interaction support. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514646(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your link. I see a lot of support for own custom controls, so i can make a context menu for my own custom control. But what I want is to determine when a ContentControl (an already existing control) on the DesignSurface is selected? Is there an event or something to check this?

Comment: I haven't used much of these. But, what your looking is Design-Time interaction tools. see the following links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514646.aspx#Tools http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.interaction.primaryselectiontaskprovider.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.interaction.selectiontool.aspx

Comment: "so i can make a context menu for my own custom control." for this also, you can create your own "Expression.Design.dll" with the help of ContextMenuProvider you can achieve this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.interaction.contextmenuprovider.contextmenuprovider(v=vs.90).aspx Probably, you need to reflect the assembly and get all the class details first.